# How to add a table to shopwares product detail page which lists all available variants for this product?

Tags: smarty, shopware

I'm trying to edit the .tpl of the article detail page in my shopware instance to be able to display a complete list of all available variants in a table view with a link in the last column to directly choose the listed variant.

https://shopware.demo2.sixhop.net/hoehenluft-abenteuer/fashion/herren/151/mi-pants-bacun?number=SW10151.5&c=5

So if there are two configuration possibilities like in this example: color and size, I would like to generate this table:

pants s green "link to variant"

pants m green "link to variant"

pants l green "link to variant"

pants xl green "link to variant"

pants xl green "link to variant"

pants s black "link to variant"

pants m black "link to variant"

pants l black "link to variant"

pants xl black "link to variant"

pants xl black "link to variant"

How can I get a list of available variants for a given base article? How is the link for this article being generated?

What I already did is to add a separate tab that can show the variant table then and some trial&error on generating the table. But simply connecting all variant possibilities will not give a good result, beacuse some variant possibilities may not be available. Therefore I would love to see an approach from the "get active variants"-perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You could work with {$sArticle.sConfigurator}. But as you wrote this wouldn't be a good result and it depends on logic in the template.

If you are familiar with PHP I'd try to create an DetailSubscriber(Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatchSecure_Frontend_Detail) and get the variants from the article itself. After this you can assign the result to a variable like $sArticleVariants and print it in the frontend.